# Is combinatorial automorphism of symmetric convex polytope always antipodal?

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes

The question is formulated in the title. More precisely, if $P$ is an origin-symmetric convex polytope in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $f$ is a bijective transform of the set of the vertices of $P$, which preserves combinatorial structure (lattice of faces of all dimensions), must it satisfy $f(x)=-f(-x)$ for all vertices $x$?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but I had some trouble understanding your question when reading it the first time. By "send symmetric vertices to symmetric" you mean that $f(-v) = -f(v)$ for all vertices $v$, right? I now see why you call such an automorphism $f$ "odd", but when reading the question first, I did not know what was meant. Is this standard usage? After all, $f$ is defined only on the set of vertices.

Comment: An equivalent version of the question is whether the symmetry $v\mapsto -v$ centralizes all the combinatorial automorphisms. Clearly, its true when $f$ is realized by an affine symmetry.

Comment: I have a feeling I am missing something, but a square centred at the origin is origin symmetric, but a rotation does not send vertices to its "opposites".  I think you might need to clarify what you mean by a symmetric vertex...

Comment: Fedor means that every pair of opposite vertices is sent to a pair of opposite vertices. The paper http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02760511#page-1 lends credence to a negative answer.

Comment: I second Frieder, but about "combinatorial structure". Do you must mean adjacency between vertices only ? Because if you meant preserving all subsets of vertices making up some facet (= codim 1 face, hence all faces), I would advance that the bijection is affine, right ?

Comment: I wrote my comment before seeing Richard's, but posted it after, unfortunately. This result is shocking ! Why isn't it more widely known ?

Comment: I mean the whole combinatorial structure, i.e. faces of all dimensions. The negative answer is definitely not what I expected!

Comment: @Fedor : Me neither ! I'm appalled ! (and now not only for events in Paris).

Comment: @Frieder, I do not know. I always thought that for being called odd the map has to be defined on a symmetric set, take values in a (possibly another) symmetric set, and satisfy functional equation $f(x)=-f(-x)$. Typical example of usage is Borsuk-Ulam theorem about odd maps from spheres to spheres.

Comment: @Fedor, well, since I think of a combinatorial automomorphism as a permutation on the set of vertices, I thought first "odd as a permutation" (that is, $\operatorname{sign}(f) = -1$), but it is of course clear that this is not what you mean. Also "having odd order" came to my mind when reading only the title. Anyway, it's clear now, and my misunderstandings are probably due to me being socialized in another area (finite groups).

Comment: Many other examples like that of Bokowski-Ewald Kleinschmidt have been found since: see http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2547803

Comment: I discovered that Fedor's question goes back to Perles. See page 1367 of Kalai's article in *Proc. ICM, Zurich, 1994*.